# how to properly use cache-control header in an HTTP request

Tags: http, caching, cdn

I have a website that caches data, it uses a content-delivery-network called `akamai`, and this is the response header.  `'cache-control': 'must-revalidate, max-age=600'`. This means, re-validate after 600 seconds (stale). If i want the cdn to query the origin server each request, i can do this... `cache-control: no-cache`. When i send this request, i get the same response header... indicating that it isn't being re-validated? Is it actually not being re-validated, or is it being re-validated? Since the website is well-known, it is safe to say that the website is correctly responding to headers.

Answer (score 2):

What you've observed is correct behavior.

Your `Cache-Control` request header applies to *this request*, while the `Cache-Control` response applies to *future requests*. Whether or not your client wants a fresh response to this request will not and should not change the server's general directions as to how its resources can be cached.

As long as you use `no-cache` in your requests you should not get a cached response.